# ASP.NET issue with jQuery 1.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-1.4, jquery-1.5

I am getting this error

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

when I use jQuery 1.5 but if I replace with jQuery 1.4 then it work fine.

I want to know what is the reason behind this?

**UPDATE :**

I got this situation also after throwing Exception if I click on back button of browser and then click button of submit it's working now.:-)

Comment: Did you try to disable the ViewState?

Comment: how is this related to jquery? What part of your code is causing this issue?

Comment: @Vijay : I removed all code which is related to Jquery only write this line <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script> but it throw error. working after remove that line..

Comment: There is a new version of jQuery: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js

Comment: I think both are same my link is http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js

Comment: They aren't. But ok, the Google version of jQuery 1.5.2: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js - By the way, I insist it's a viewstate problem. Did you try to create an HTML page to test?

Comment: @Davis : Jquery 1.5.5 of google and aspnetcdn are same I compare them on file compare you can also clear your doubt http://www.comparemyfiles.com/

Comment: Try this: http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/09/22/91998.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="false"  %>
```